# Jenkins web authentication intermittently fails

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins within Tomcat 7.
I want to log in and operate Jenkins securely over the web.

I set up an admin user and password. Logging in with these credentials works fine initially.

Then, after a while, I try to log in but submitting my login request just sends me back to the login screen (but *without* the "Invalid login information. Please try again." message).

I have to hack around it by disabling security in config.xml, and re-enabling it via the "Configure Global Security" page. I've tried two different Security Realms: "Jenkins’ own user database" and "Unix user/group database". They both work initially then eventually fail.